# Причины серийного голосованиия в отношении одного участника

Tags: обсуждение, голосование, голоса-за

Какие могут быть причины серийного голосования в отношении одного участника?

Возможные мотивы могут быть, например, коллеги поддерживают друг друга и плюсуют иногда соседу по офису.

Comment: Может быть и их отсутствие. Люди такие люди. На самом деле, кое-что модераторы про голоса видят. Больше нас.

Comment: К примеру, может быть такая ситуация, человек читает что-то по определенному тегу, изучает, тут ему к примеру подошло решение определенного человека, он дальше смотрит уже, что и как отвечал этот человек, смотрит ответ адекватный и допустим ему подошёл и т.д., ставит плюсы само собой.

Comment: Серийное голосование - это не всегда плохо. К сожалению, систему автоотката этому не научили.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, что плохого. Я один пример привёл. А ещё какие есть, которые не по попадают под "накрут"? Вот VladSpirin тоже мыслимый вариант предложил.

Comment: Вот это - "коллеги по работе поддерживают" - как раз и есть накрутка...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Почему? Если  они сидят весь рабочий день и только этим и занимаются, то да. Или, что они постоянно просчитывают - на сегодня для Петрова хватит, а то автоаткат будет - я не имел ввиду и, думаю, так никто не делает.

Comment: @0xdb, если они голосуют _только_ за тебя - то вполне себе накрутка

Comment: @Grundy Нет, они нормальные участники и голосую также и за других и в  других вопросах. Я этот случай имел ввиду.

Comment: Не понимаю сути вопроса. Вы хотите знать, с какой целью люди серийно голосуют или что система считает серийным голосованием (накруткой)?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Первое,  по накрутке уже достаточно ответов. А почему не понятно? Второе предложение в вопросе в заблуждение вводит?

Comment: Коллеги по работе часто интересуются одними и теми же тегами. Поэтому часто не мудрено, что "апают" друг друга.